# Split list into N sublists with approximately equal sums

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of integers, and I need to split it into a given number of sublists (with no restrictions on order or the number of elements in each), in a way that minimizes the average difference in sums of each sublist.

For example:

```
>>> x = [4, 9, 1, 5]
>>> sublist_creator(x, 2)
[[9], [4, 1, 5]]
```

because `list(map(sum, sublist_creator(x, 2)))` yields `[9, 10]`, minimizing the average distance. Alternatively, `[[9, 1], [4, 5]]` would have been equally correct, and my use case has no preference between two possibilities.

The only way I can think of to do this is by checking, iteratively, all possible combinations, but I'm working with a list of ~5000 elements and need to split it into ~30 sublists, so that approach is prohibitively expensive.

Comment: Do you need a provably minimal difference, or is it good enough to get something approximate?  @lenik's answer -- a nicely intelligent "greedy" algorithm -- will give you a good approximation.  If fact, I think it will give you the minimal answer in most "nicely"-distributed sets of numbers.

Comment: In my case, I'm just trying to take a dataset and segment it onto different hardware based on the number of datapoints, and want it to be roughly evenly distributed - so approximate is good enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the outline:

1. create `N` empty lists
2. `sort()` your input array in ascending order
3. `pop()` the last element from the sorted array
4. `append()` the popped element to the list with the lowest `sum()` of the elements
5. repeat 3 and 4 until input array is empty
6. profit!!!

With M=5000 elements and N=30 lists this approach might take about O(N*M) if you carefully store the intermediate sums of the sublists instead of calculating them from the scratch every time.

Comment: I think there may be a factor of log N in there. I'm thinking of keeping the lists in a min-heap as you go. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MadPhysicist that might work too, I just don't want to overload OP with the names of the various external libraries and python modules, keeping things simple

Comment: Fair enough. This is just between you and me in the comments. I was wondering if I'm missing an O(M * N) implementation. The best I can think of is O(M * NlogN).

Comment: @MadPhysicist actually, I don't see why O(M*NlogN), it's more like O(MlogN), because we have to loop over the M elements, take the lowest sum from the presorted list (=O(1)), then add the element to the list, update the sum and find the proper place in a sorted list, which is O(logN) -- all in all O(MlogN)

Answer (score 8):

@lenik's solution has the right idea, but can use a heap queue that keeps track of the total of each sub-list and its index in sorted order to improve the cost of finding the sub-list of the minimum size to *O(log n)*, resulting in an overall *O(m x log n)* time complexity:

```
import heapq

def sublist_creator(lst, n):
    lists = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    totals = [(0, i) for i in range(n)]
    heapq.heapify(totals)
    for value in lst:
        total, index = heapq.heappop(totals)
        lists[index].append(value)
        heapq.heappush(totals, (total + value, index))
    return lists
```

so that:

```
sublist_creator(x, 2)
```

returns:

```
[[4, 1, 5], [9]]
```

Comment: The best solution so far out of 6 found on stackoverflow. Gives the most even distribution.

Comment: It's giving different results upon list shuffling. You can try it on this list, shuffling it a few times: [3.71000e+02,2.03330e+04,2.19267e+05,1.44631e+05,5.78250e+04,4.28350e+04,2.36407e+05,1.18678e+05,2.33142e+05,1.06070e+05,6.22000e+02,9.40440e+04,8.22230e+04,5.01510e+04,1.90301e+05,1.65925e+05,1.47590e+04,7.08640e+04,3.08182e+05,9.60290e+04,2.44983e+05,4.52930e+04,7.05670e+04,6.04388e+05,0.00000e+00,4.25000e+02,8.20460e+04] Results are different and clearly suboptimal. Unless the input being pre-sorted desc is a requirement?

Answer (score 3):

Implementation of [@lennik's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61648188/2988730) using python's underrated priority queue module [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html). This follows his idea pretty much exactly, except that each list is given a first element that contains its sum. Since lists are sorted lexicography and `heapq` is a min-heap implementation, all we have to do is pop off the first elements after we finish.

Using [`heapreplace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapreplace) will help avoid unnecessary resizing operations during the updates.

```
from heapq import heapreplace

def sublist_creator(x, n, sort=True):
    bins = [[0] for _ in range(n)]
    if sort:
        x = sorted(x, reverse=True)
    for i in x:
        least = bins[0]
        least[0] += i
        least.append(i)
        heapreplace(bins, least)
    return [x[1:] for x in bins]
```

Given `M = len(x)` and `N = n`, the sort is `O(M log M)` and the loop does `M` insertions, which are `O(log N)` worst case. So for `M >= N`, we can say that asymptotically the algorithm is `O(M log M)`. If the array is pre-sorted, it's `O(M log N)`.

Comment: Shouldn't this be sorted(x, reverse=True) to make sure you loop over the items from largest to smallest?

Comment: @pstjohn. Looking back at this, I think you're right. Alternatively, one might iterate over `reversed(x)`.